# App links for iOS using xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, applinks, rivets

Using Xamarin.forms and getting AndroidAppLinks on NuGetPackages I'm able to associate links to my app and makes it open the page I want. I'm trying to do the same with iOS. About this, I have two questions:

1. Do this kind of thing exists?
2. How do I make it?

I have already override the method `protected override void OnAppLinkRequestReceived(Uri uri)` on App.xaml.cs, I have also registered the the entry with `Application.Current.AppLinks.RegisterLink(entry)` and I have tryied to change Info.plist adding this entry:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>http://relacionamento.com.br/senha</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
      <string>Viewer</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>example</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

I have tryied to use Rivets but I got this for Android:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.          0

And this for iOS:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not install package 'Microsoft.Bcl.Build 1.0.14'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Trying to install in the forms, I got:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Could not install package 'Rivets 1.0.5'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does
>   not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.           0

Do I must to use Rivets?
What more do I need to use those links?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iOS equivalent of Android App Links is called **Universal Links**, and was introduced with iOS 9. To my knowledge there is no Nuget package for enabling Universal Links on Xamarin, but there is a pretty detailed walkthrough for setting everything up available [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/11/03/taking-advantage-of-the-ios-9-universal-links-on-xamarin-ios-apps/).

The Rivets package is for [*Facebook* App Links](http://applinks.org) — a completely different standard that just happens to have an identical name.

An alternative for handling all of these things at once is the [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team) deep linking platform. This is [available as a Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Branch-Xamarin-Linking-SDK/1.2.0) and you can find full documentation [here](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/sdk-integration-guide/guide/xamarin/).

Comment: Hi @Alex-Bauer firstly, thank you! In Android I've not created a Digital Asset Link (that JSON in my domain) but nevertheless I am using this without problems. In iOS is it necessary?

Comment: Also, it seems to me that I have used exactly the AppLinks by using the "AndroidAppLinks" package and, in Android, it does exactly what I want. Is it not possible in iOS? What is the difference between these types of links AppLinks and UniversalLinks?

Comment: They are totally separate standards. Universal Links is by Apple for iOS, and App Links is by Google for Android. The manner in which they operate is similar (using a verified domain to make standard `http` URLs work with apps), but there are no shared implementation steps or code. The Digital Asset Link JSON on Android is semi-optional (your users will see a pop-up option if it does not exist) but the equivalent `apple-app-site-association` file on iOS is mandatory.